# spark 2.2.0, calling cache() gets different results if there is an append

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am puzzled by this piece of code and I wonder if it is a bug of spark. I've managed to narrow it down to this testcase:

```
val path = tempFolder
Seq(1, 2).toDS.write.parquet(path)

val loaded = spark.read.parquet(path).as[Int]
val filtered = loaded.filter(_ < 2)
  .cache() // this line creates the problem. Remove it and filtered.toSet is Set(1)

Seq(-1,-2).toDS.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(path)

// this should be the correct value
//    filtered.collect.toSet should be(Set(1))

// but instead we get this incorrect value
filtered.collect.toSet should be(Set(-1,-2,1))
```

So as you can see, filtered reads the appended data. One might say that this is OK since spark always lazy-evals everything. But it shouldn't be the case because filtered is a transformation on loaded which should contain only [1,2]. Also if I remove the .cache() then filtered is indeed only [1] which is the correct value in my opinion and is in pair with what usually I expect to get from spark.

Do you think this is a bug?